# Передача указателя/ссылки/объекта в аргументы функции?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Имеется такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void create_list(node* &top,int n)
{
    int i;
    node* p;
    top = new node;
    top = NULL;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p=new node;
        cout<<" enter p->data=";
        cin>>p->data;
        p->next=top;
        top=p;
    }   
}

main(){
    int n;
    node* top_my_list;
    cout<<"enter n= ";
    cin>>n;
    create_list(top_my_list,n);
    cout << top_my_list->data;
}
```

**И собственно вопрос:** Правильно ли я понимаю что при вызове функции create_list мы посылаем ей указатель на структуру а в процессе самой передачи происходит "разыменование" указателя вот здесь **&top**(в аргументах create_list), а далее обращение к самому значению объекта с помощью * То есть мы передаем в функцию значение объекта на который указывает top_my_list ?

Или же мы все такие передаем ссылку на указатель типа node?!(Если да то каким именно образом это происходит).

Или что вообще мы передаем?

**P.S. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не правильно. Функция `create_list` принимает указатель на `node`, а вот `&` в объявление функции значит, что мы передаём указатель по ссылке, а не по значению.

---

В C++ есть два способа передать объект в функцию: [по ссылке и по значению](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?click=013-1.aspx.htm). Когда мы передаём объект по значению

```
void plus(int n) {
    n++;
}
```

мы делаем его копии и в функции модифицируем его копию:

```
int n = 4;
plus(n);
// n не изменилось и всё также равняется четырём
```

Когда мы передаём объект по ссылке, то мы (как бы) вводим внутри функции альтернативное имя для этой переменной:

```
void plusplus(int &n) {
    n++;
}
```

теперь если вызвать эту функцию, то тот объект, от которого эта функция вызывается изменится:

```
int n = 4;
plusplus(n);
// n изменилось и теперь равно 5
```

---

В вашем случае функция принимает указатель на `node`, но принимает его именно по ссылке. То есть может модифицировать внешнюю переменную внутри себя.

Comment: То есть мы передаем ссылку на указатель или адрес указателя, локальному указателю top?(З.Ы. не бейте тапком, не пойму никак). Можно подробнее, пожалуйста. И спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Aiswe мы передаём указатель по ссылке. (Добавил в ответ про передачу по ссылке). Прочитайте что-нибудь [такое](http://itandlife.ru/programming/cpp/ukazateli-i-ssylki-v-c/) про ссылки и указатели. Это полезно. Указатели и ссылки это разные сущности стоит их понимать и знать различия. (Условно указатель -- адрес, а ссылка -- альтернативное имя)

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ(разобрался), я понимаю отличия ссылки от указателя, просто само выражение * & вызывает странные чувства, ведь:

{ int i = 10; }                                                                                                           

{ int &p = i; //объявление ссылки, если можно так выразиться, псевдонима переменной i }
{ int *pp = &i;//присвоение указателю адреса объекта i }

{ cout<< *pp;//мы получим значение самого объекта с помощью оператора обращения к значению * }

Comment: Да, всё так. Можно теперь даже создать ссылку на pp: `int* &rpp = pp;`

Comment: ссылка имеет тип указателя на int, верно ?

Comment: @Aiswe Да, ссылка указывает на (создаёт альтернативное имя для) `int*`( указатель на `int`).